# Google Drive API V3 Javascript - Create File with Content

Tags: javascript, file, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

This question has been asked before, but the answer was using API V2. The google documentation does not clarify how to create a file with its content using javascript client code. I tried using the code listed under Node, however, it only creates the file, it does not insert any content. Here is my code:

```
  let fileMetadata = {
    'name': name,
    parents: [parentId]
  };

  let media = {
    mimeType: 'text/plain',
    body: 'content inside file'
  };

  gapi.client.drive.files.create({
    resource: fileMetadata,
    media,
    fields: 'id'
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log('response: ', response);
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('something is wrong');
  });
```

Can someone help me insert content into files please?

Comment: I have also experienced about your situation. ``gapi.client.drive.files.create()`` can create an empty file. But it seems that it cannot directly upload a file with contents. This might be able to be resolved in the future update. So in the current stage, I upload files to Google Drive using XMLHttpRequest as a workaround. For your situation, how about this workaround?

Comment: I think that is the only course to take, thanks Tanaike.

Comment: Welcome. If you need a sample script, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `media: media,` instead of `media,`? It's a bit tough to determine the type of upload being issued by the client library, but to add both metadata and content you need to either use a resumable or multipart upload. Specifying the upload type may be an additional parameter to the JS client. Also, you should probably link to the related question.

Comment: 'media' is written correctly, it's ES6 shorthand when key and value in an object have the same name. I tried setting the multipart download type in the 'create' invocation, but also didn't work.

Comment: Tanaike can you send your sample script please?

Comment: I posted a sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this sample script? In my environment, although `gapi.client.drive.files.create()` can create an empty file on Google Drive, it cannot directly upload files including contents. I think that this might not be able to upload files and metadata with the multipart/related, although this might be resolved by the future update. So now, as one of workarounds, I use XMLHttpRequest.

Before you use this sample script, please confirm the following points.

- In your situation, you have already been able to create files using gapi. In my script, the access token is retrieved using gapi.
- When you use this script, please set fileContent and metadata.

#### Sample script :

In this sample script, a text file including contents is created under a folder.

```
var fileContent = 'sample text'; // As a sample, upload a text file.
var file = new Blob([fileContent], {type: 'text/plain'});
var metadata = {
    'name': 'sampleName', // Filename at Google Drive
    'mimeType': 'text/plain', // mimeType at Google Drive
    'parents': ['### folder ID ###'], // Folder ID at Google Drive
};

var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token; // Here gapi is used for retrieving the access token.
var form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {type: 'application/json'}));
form.append('file', file);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log(xhr.response.id); // Retrieve uploaded file ID.
};
xhr.send(form);
```

#### Request body :

In this script, `form` is as follows. This is sent to Google Drive using the create method of Drive API.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryxX0XmxgooMjdUECR
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

{"name":"sampleName","mimeType":"text/plain","parents":["#####"]}
------WebKitFormBoundaryxX0XmxgooMjdUECR
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: text/plain

sample text
------WebKitFormBoundaryxX0XmxgooMjdUECR--
```

In my environment, I confirmed that this works fine. But if this didn't work in your environment, I'm sorry.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @Philip-lf Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Comment: it work thank you , @Tanaike also upload the new version with fetch in his blog here https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/08/13/upload-files-to-google-drive-using-javascript/