# Angular gapi upload simple text to Google Drive

Tags: angular, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a simple text file to Google Drive in Angular using `gapi`, but I can't find how to actually populate the file. I managed to authenticate and create a file, and then I wanted to use the `update` function to update the file's contents as described [here in the Google Drive API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update).

Here is my Angular code:

Creating the file:

```
createFile() {
    return gapi.client.drive.files.create({
      resource: {
        name: `test.csv`
      }
    }).then(response => {
      console.log("Response", response.result.id);
      return response.result.id;
    })
  }
```

This creates the file and I can see it in my Drive's root folder. Then I try to add the contents of this file (using the file ID of the file I just created) but it is not clear to me from the documentation how to pass the content in the `update` call.

```
  updateFile(fileId) {
    return gapi.client.drive.files.update({
      fileId: fileId,
      body: "this is the content of my file"
    }).then(response => {
      console.log("Response", response);
    })
  }
```

I also tried to pass the content directly in the `create` call, based on the example they give in the documentation (link above)

```
  createFile() {
    return gapi.client.drive.files.create({
      resource: {
        name: `test.csv`
      },
      media: {
        body: "this is the content of my file"
      }
    }).then(response => {
      console.log("Response", response.result.id);
    })
  }
```

Though this doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi @vdvaxel, how are you using/loading gapi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to upload a text file to Google Drive by including the content using Javascript.
- You have already been able to get and put value for Google Drive using Drive API.
- Your access token can be used for uploading a file to Google Drive.

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that `gapi.client.drive.files.create` cannot still send the request including the content. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51775917) And, when I tested the update method using `gapi` now, I think that `gapi.client.drive.files.update` cannot also send the request including the content.

So in this case, it is required to use a workaround. In this workaround, `fetch` is used. When `fetch` is used, the request of `multipart/form-data` is easily created.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the text file is uploaded to Google Drive by including the content using the create method with `fetch`.

#### Sample script:

```
const content = 'this is the content of my file';
const metadata = {name: 'test.txt', mimeType: 'text/plain'};
let form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {type: 'application/json'}));
form.append('file', new Blob([content], {type: 'text/plain'}));
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + gapi.auth.getToken().access_token}),
  body: form
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(val => console.log(val));
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the text file is created by `gapi.client.drive.files.create`, and the created text file is updated by the update method of Drive API with `fetch`.

#### Sample script:

```
gapi.client.drive.files.create({resource: {name: 'test.txt'}})
.then(response => {
  const fileId = response.result.id;
  const content = 'this is the content of my file';
  const metadata = {name: 'test.txt', mimeType: 'text/plain'};
  let form = new FormData();
  form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {type: 'application/json'}));
  form.append('file', new Blob([content], {type: 'text/plain'}));
  fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/' + fileId + '?uploadType=multipart', {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + gapi.auth.getToken().access_token}),
    body: form
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(val => console.log(val));
});
```

### References:

- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear answer! I went for option one and it worked fine

Comment: @vdvaxel Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.