# Getting permission denied error while uploading image on Google Drive by Google Drive API Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

This is the code to upload image on my Google Drive, then get the url and delete if needed and it was working perfectly.

```
function uploadImageInFolderAndGetVisibleDocURL(imgName, url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const fileName = imgName;
    var folderId = '01220GsMOG727b2TxnSB_7zkgAFcygd';
    fetch(url).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {
      const form = new FormData();
      form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify({name: fileName, parents: [folderId]})], {type: 'application/json'}));
      form.append('file', blob);
      fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + gapi.auth.getToken().access_token}),
        body: form
      }).then(res => res.json()).then(val => resolve(["https://drive.google.com/uc?id="+val.id, val.id]));
    });
  });
}

function deleteGoogleDocImageByPhotoID(photoID) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.delete({
      'fileId': photoID
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      resolve("success");
    });
  });
}
```

Today I made another Project on Google Console with different Google account. Here I gave different name of my project. I got different `apiKey` & `clientId`. But when It comes to provide the main URL and redirect url on my Google Developer Console, I put the same, because my web app url is fixed and it's the one I got. I have enabled the Google Drive API on my new Google Console and the parents folder in which I am uploading my image is set to public just like my previous account.

But strangely It is giving me this error while uploading image:
`POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart 403`
Point to this line:
`fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart',`

[image]

When I come back to my code and set my previous `apiKey` & `clientId` and run project it's still giving me the same error. But this was working perfectly before setting up the 2nd new project on different Google Account. Why is this happening? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advanced.

**PS: I run my project on Chrome incognito mode.**

Error in expand mode:

```
(anonymous) @   upload.js:87
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   upload.js:82
uploadImageInFolderAndGetVisibleDocURL  @   upload.js:80
postOnGoogleDrive   @   wallpapers.js:138
(anonymous) @   wallpapers.js:203
e.g @   promise.js:832
ae  @   promise.js:1171
oe  @   promise.js:1145
t.Zb    @   promise.js:1116
Kt  @   run.js:132
Promise.then (async)        
Dt  @   run.js:63
Ut  @   run.js:42
ie  @   promise.js:1034
ee  @   promise.js:927
t.Oc    @   promise.js:870
(anonymous) @   promise.js:996
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   promise.js:1008
ne  @   promise.js:1010
ee  @   promise.js:916
(anonymous) @   promise.js:175
e.g @   promise.js:832
ae  @   promise.js:1171
oe  @   promise.js:1145
t.Zb    @   promise.js:1116
Kt  @   run.js:132
Promise.then (async)        
Dt  @   run.js:63
Ut  @   run.js:42
ie  @   promise.js:1034
Qt  @   promise.js:797
te  @   promise.js:853
qt.then @   promise.js:577
t.cc    @   auth.js:1485
Ve.getAuthToken @   authwrapper.ts:96
qe.getDownloadURL   @   reference.ts:336
complete    @   wallpapers.js:199
(anonymous) @   async.ts:26
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   async.ts:26
Be.notifyObserver_  @   task.ts:637
(anonymous) @   task.ts:599
Be.notifyObservers_ @   task.ts:598
Be.transition_  @   task.ts:418
(anonymous) @   task.ts:284
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   task.ts:278
(anonymous) @   task.ts:177
e.g @   promise.js:832
ae  @   promise.js:1171
oe  @   promise.js:1145
t.Zb    @   promise.js:1116
Kt  @   run.js:132
Promise.then (async)        
Dt  @   run.js:63
Ut  @   run.js:42
ie  @   promise.js:1034
Qt  @   promise.js:797
te  @   promise.js:853
qt.then @   promise.js:577
t.cc    @   auth.js:1485
Ve.getAuthToken @   authwrapper.ts:96
Be.resolveToken_    @   task.ts:174
Be.continueUpload_  @   task.ts:253
Be.start_   @   task.ts:163
Be.completeTransitions_ @   task.ts:433
(anonymous) @   task.ts:286
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   task.ts:278
(anonymous) @   task.ts:177
e.g @   promise.js:832
ae  @   promise.js:1171
oe  @   promise.js:1145
t.Zb    @   promise.js:1116
Kt  @   run.js:132
Promise.then (async)        
Dt  @   run.js:63
Ut  @   run.js:42
ie  @   promise.js:1034
Qt  @   promise.js:797
te  @   promise.js:853
qt.then @   promise.js:577
t.cc    @   auth.js:1485
Ve.getAuthToken @   authwrapper.ts:96
Be.resolveToken_    @   task.ts:174
Be.continueUpload_  @   task.ts:253
Be.start_   @   task.ts:163
Be.completeTransitions_ @   task.ts:433
(anonymous) @   task.ts:286
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? In your situation, the owner of the folder of `1H6QCH0GsMOG727b2TxnSB_7zkgAFcygd` is the same with the owner of this access token `gapi.auth.getToken().access_token`? If this is not the same, is the folder publicly shared as the writer?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes Sir. The owner is the same.

Comment: `example1@gmail.com` > Google Drive folder ID1 and access_token_1 & `example2@gmail.com` > Google Drive folder ID2 and access_token_2

Comment: All my code related to upload, get and delete on Google Drive is in this one file called `upload.js` so there's no chance to mismatch.

Comment: Thank you for replying and more information. When the owners of the folder and access token are the same, I think that the script works. So I would like to try whether I can replicate your situation. If I could replicate it and found the solution, I will propose the modification point.

Comment: Ok Sir. I am getting the `access_token` perfectly for both account. `alert(gapi.auth.getToken().access_token);` So the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: please include the full error message there are like 10 403 errors.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for your comment. I have attached it. Please check.

Comment: What scope did you use to authorize this user?

Comment: This one `var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly';`

Comment: @Tanaike, DalmTo I have deleted my 2nd account credentials and now it's started working again. I think Google doesn't allow to make multiple pointer with same URL to their Google Drive Console.

Comment: Correct me if I wrong sir. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. I apologize for this. When I could replicate your situation, I would like to think of the solution. By the way, from the scope you are using, when you want to upload the file, how about modifying it to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`?

Comment: Thanks for keep listening me Sir. No it is the same with new `SCOPE`. Sir, let me add some more information. Say in `example1@gmail.com` I hosted my web app. My Webapp is using the Firebase cloud database and Storage of this `example1@gmail.com` account. I use the Firebase authentication to login in to my webapp. And it is also associated with `example1@gmail.com`. Now after login to my webapp, there is a `Sign In with Google` button.

Comment: Now I have a 2nd google account `example2@gmail.com`. I want to upload my images in the Google Drive of this 2nd `example2@gmail.com` account by authenticating with the help of `Sign In with Google` button. So my main web app will be hosted on a fixed gmail account (`example1@gmail.com` in this case) but the images could be uploaded on different gmail account. Now it's `example2@gmail.com`, later may be `example3@gmail.com`.

Comment: So it is working perfectly when I upload my image on `example1@gmail.com`. But when I try to upload images on `example2@gmail.com` with it's own `APIkey` & `clientID` both of them stop uploading image. I have to delete my 2nd account Google Developer Console credentials to make it workable again.

Comment: This kind of issue is common when you are signed in simultaneously with several accounts into your browser session. When you want to use `example2@gmail.com` - make sure that beforehand you sign out of all your other accounts.

Comment: @ziganotschka And now although I have deleted the credentials from the Google Developer Console of the `example2@gmail.com`, my `example1@gmail.com` is stop working and keep giving 403 (Permission Denied) error! Is it temporary or is it permanent? Can you please ensure me that? Thanks!

Comment: @ziganotschka I always run my web app on Chrome safe mode to avoid session complexity. But it's still giving me 403 for upload, 404 for get and 405 for delete!

Comment: Not sure if this the issue, but when uploading a file with metadata you should use `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files` instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files`, see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create). If you want to try a different approach - have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61727638/how-to-insert-file-to-a-shared-drive-using-rest-on-apps-script/61776451#61776451) Apps Script implementation - should work the same way in Javascript.